# how to fill the default new row with some data without adding the row in wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have default a new empty row in datagrid (acts as a footer row) . i want to type in barcode of the footer row and press enter . then it fetches some values and should populate the remaining cells item , mrp , cgst , sgst , discount , amount , salesman (except qty) . after populating the fields , the focus should go to quantity cell . type quantity and press enter , then this footer row should be added to datagrid and another new empty footer row should be created with focus on barcode . this is what i want to do

right now im stuck because i dont know how to populate the new row with values (wihtout adding the row to the datagrid) ..

XAML

```
<Grid  Margin="59,59,89,0">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,33,10,37" PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown" />

</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    void CreateDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn No = new DataColumn("No",typeof(double));
        DataColumn Barcode = new DataColumn("Barcode", typeof(string));
        DataColumn Item = new DataColumn("Item", typeof(string));
        DataColumn Qty = new DataColumn("Qty", typeof(double));
        DataColumn Mrp = new DataColumn("Mrp", typeof(double));
        DataColumn Discount = new DataColumn("Discount", typeof(double));
        DataColumn Cgst = new DataColumn("Cgst", typeof(double));
        DataColumn Sgst = new DataColumn("Sgst", typeof(double));
        DataColumn Amount = new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(double));
        DataColumn Salesman = new DataColumn("Salesman", typeof(string));

        dt.Columns.Add(No);
        dt.Columns.Add(Barcode);
        dt.Columns.Add(Item);
        dt.Columns.Add(Qty);
        dt.Columns.Add(Mrp);
        dt.Columns.Add(Discount);
        dt.Columns.Add(Cgst);
        dt.Columns.Add(Sgst);
        dt.Columns.Add(Amount);
        dt.Columns.Add(Salesman);
       
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CreateDataTable();
    }
   
    private void dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRowIndex = dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(dataGrid.CurrentItem);

        // move focus to next field

        var uiElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && uiElement != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            FillBarcodeData(currentRowIndex);
            dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid.Items[currentRowIndex], dataGrid.Columns[3]);
            dataGrid.BeginEdit();
        }
    }

    public void FillBarcodeData(int currentRowIndex)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();                     
    }
```

Comment: Why not scan your barcode into a textbox instead, do the lookups and add the row? Or not have a textbox at all and process the keypresses invisibly?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the visual tree of your DataGrid after starting the application in Debug, you will see that the DataContext of the last (empty) row is not an item in your collection, but the value of the [static property NewItemPlaceholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.newitemplaceholder?view=net-5.0).

For this reason, the cells of this row do not contain some empty data (which could be replaced with yours), but, in fact, only the borders of the cells.
Since there is no element of which this line represents, it is accordingly not possible to change the data of this nonexistent element.

BUT it can be done when you start editing this line.
At this point, two events are created sequentially.

1. [AddingNewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.addingnewitem?view=net-5.0) - in it you can create the desired item yourself. If null is returned, then it will be created by the DataGrid by default constructor.
2. [InitializingNewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.initializingnewitem?view=net-5.0)- in it you can get an already created item and change its properties.

Example:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace NewRowDataTable
{
    public class RowData
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class RowsViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<RowData> Rows { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<RowData>()
            {
                new RowData(){Number=1, Text="First"},
                new RowData(){Number=2, Text="Second"}
            };
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="NewRowDataTable.NewRowWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NewRowDataTable"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="NewRowWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <local:RowsViewModel/>
    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}"
                  AddingNewItem="OnAddingNewRow"
                  InitializingNewItem="OnInitializingNewRow"/>
    </Grid>
    <x:Code><![CDATA[
        private void OnAddingNewRow(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            e.NewItem = new RowData() {Text="Some data", Number=789};
        }

        private void OnInitializingNewRow(object sender, InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            RowData data = (RowData) e.NewItem;
            data.Number *= 10;
            data.Text += "+Init";
        }

        ]]></x:Code>
</Window>
```